# Parsing CSV File to MySQL DB in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file-io, csv

I have a some 350-lined CSV File with all sorts of vendors that fall into Clothes, Tools, Entertainment, etc.. categories. Using the following code I have been able to print out my CSV File.

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen('promo_catalog_expanded.csv', 'r'); 
    echo '<tr><td>'; 
    echo implode('</td><td>', fgetcsv($fp, 4096, ',')); 
    echo '</td></tr>'; 
    while(!feof($fp)) { 
        list($cat, $var, $name, $var2, $web, $var3, $phone,$var4, $kw,$var5, $desc) = fgetcsv($fp, 4096); 
        echo '<tr><td>'; 
        echo $cat. '</td><td>' . $name . '</td><td><a href="http://www.' . $web .'" target="_blank">' .$web.'</a></td><td>'.$phone.'</td><td>'.$kw.'</td><td>'.$desc.'</td>' ;
        echo '</td></tr>'; 
    } 

    fclose($file_handle); 
    show_source(__FILE__); 
?>
```

First thing you will probably notice is the extraneous vars within the list(). this is because of how the excel spreadsheet/csv file:

```
Category,,Company Name,,Website,,Phone,,Keywords,,Description  
,,,,,,,,,,  
Clothes,,4imprint,,4imprint.com,,877-466-7746,,"polos, jackets, coats, workwear, sweatshirts, hoodies, long sleeve, pullovers,  t-shirts, tees, tshirts,",,An embroidery and apparel company based in Wisconsin.
,,Apollo Embroidery,,apolloemb.com,,1-800-982-2146,,"hats, caps, headwear, bags, totes, backpacks, blankets, embroidery",,An embroidery sales company based in California.
```

One thing to note is that the last line starts with two commas as it is also listed within "Clothes" category.

My concern is that I am going about the CSV output wrong.

Should I be using a foreach loop instead of this list way?
Should I first get rid of any unnecessary blank columns?

Please advise any flaws you may find, improvements I can use so I can be ready to import this data to a MySQL DB.

Comment: Are you aware of `LOAD DATA INFILE`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Ever had a look at the MySQL `LOAD DATA` command? I would let MySQL handle the CSV directly, move everything into a temp table and update your real data from there. Why write extra plumbing code in PHP?

Comment: The only problem with LOAD DATA is that if he is doing this live on the server he may not have the privs to execute it.

Comment: haven't used `LOAD DATA` before, I will look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure of the overall structure of your CSV - its hard to make rule assumptions based on two lines... but something like the following should work:

```
$fp = fopen('promo_catalog_expanded.csv', 'r');

// normalize the column names
$columns = array_change_key_case(fgetcsv($fp, 0, ','), CASE_LOWER);
$lastCategory = null;

while(false !== ($data = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ','))) {
   $data = array_combine($columns, $data); // make it an assoc array

   // test if category has a value - if it doesnt use the last category
   if(empty($data['category']) && null !== $lastCategory ){
      $data['category'] = $lastCategory;
   }

   // if we have started a new set of entries for a cat, we need to make it the $lastCategory
   if($lastCategory !== $dataCategory && null !== $data['category']) {
      $lastCategory = $data['category'];
   }

   // your sql to do the insert

}
```

Comment: End of categories are designated by an empty row as you see at the beginning before Clothes: `,,,,,,,,,,`

Thank you for your code, I'll be looking into modifying it.